# How to hide a single value/row in phpmyadmin 4.0

Tags: javascript, php, sql, phpmyadmin

How to hide a single value in phpmyadmin 4.0 without deleteing it so it will not show on the auto populate field on the website?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry not getting your requirement. PhpMyAdmin is tool to view database/tables information. Do you want to hide row or not display row into your application? Please describe in detail

Comment: I would like to hide an entire row. Thanks